# Input format(mask) like vue directive

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, input, formatting

I need a behavior when I enter in input like that:

1. only numbers are available for entering
2. the last two digits entered are separated from the previous ones by a dot

For example: Keyboard input "5" - displays in input "0.05". Keyboard input "1005" - displays in input "10.05".

Is that what i have now:

```
Vue.directive('format', {
  bind(el: HTMLElement, binding: any, vnode: VNode) {
    const { modifiers } = binding;
    const targetElement = el;

    if (modifiers.cost) {
      targetElement.addEventListener('input', (e: any) => {
        e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
      });
    }
  },
  update(el: HTMLElement, binding: any, vnode: VNode) {
    const { modifiers } = binding;
    const targetElement = el;

    if (modifiers.cost) {
      targetElement.addEventListener('input', (e: any) => {
        e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
      });
    }
  },
});
```

I would really appreciate for some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can specify `type="number"` in your `input` tag". It will only accept numbers. You can also set restrictions on what numbers are accepted. Like so:
2. Use `filter` from Vue. In your Vue instance

.

```
new Vue({
    ...
    filters: {
        addDot(number) {
            return number / 100
        }
    },
    //your other properties
})
```

Then in the input tag:

```
<input type="number" min="0" :value="inputNumber | addDot" />
```

Make sure to have variable `inputNumber` in your data property, which is basically where you store the input value

Comment: Hi, thanks. But its not for me. I need Vue directive, not Vue filter. I need a good regular expression after my,
e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''). **replace(i can't do right mask here)**